# Dynamic content with jQuery and AJAX- tags moving around?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a very weird problem with jQuery moving a string echoed with a PHP tag outside of the parent tag. I've seen this behavior twice now.

I use the jquery ajax method to request modules. Occasionally, this behavior occurs:

Source:

```
<textarea id='job[description]' class='jobForm' rows="3" cols='20'/><?php echo $job->description; ?></textarea>
```

When it arrives on the other side of my AJAX request, it renders as this:

```
<textarea id='job[description]' class='jobForm' rows="3" cols='20'/></textarea>My Job Description
```

I've seen this a couple times, and I have no idea why it's happening. All the other places I do that around this one particular tag work fine and dandy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is probably seeing the `/>` at the end of your start tag and treating it as an XML-style empty element tag. Get rid of the `/`.